# C++ - Segmentation fault when declaring and initializing an int

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, int

I'm noticing that whenever I am declaring or initializing `int c = 0`, I seem to get a segmentation fault. It is only when I comment out that particular line of my code that it works fine. Here is a portion of my code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;

struct alphabet{
     int first;
     char word[30];
};
```

I've tested my code with just `a` and `b` as my only integers. It only began giving me that the segmentation fault once I tried initializing `c` later on. I just don't understand why this would even happen. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem is in the code that you didn't post.  Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's a flaw in another part of your code and it's overwriting some piece of memory. Adding `c` is causing the layout in memory to change and making the overwrite in a place that causes a crash rather than you not noticing.

Comment: Use your debugger to find out _where_ the segfault occurs. This may give you a hint about what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have posted a very short peace of code, it is hard to give you a concrete advise. Hovewer, let's try as for the 'average' case. All your three `int` variables are located at the stack frame. Thus, adding more variables like `c` you may move the location of the rest stack variables which may be defined later. In particular, if you instantiate an instance of your structure `alphabet` which has an array field `word`. Imagine what happens if you underrun it (out of baundary access to the left baundary of the array). In the case if this underrun overlaps the area where `c` is located and you write to it by initializing `c`, then potentially string operation on `word` may crash. So, my advise would be do a code review starting down from the this function. Focus is on using uninitialized variables, out of boundary access and hanging pointers in respect to stack variables. A good practice would also be to use some static code analysis tool. For more concrete hints you need to extend your question to give more details as is recommended in the comments above.